# SocketConnection in Android - with Stream Data

Tags: android, sockets, post, tcp, get

Can we connect below URL as a socket ?
http://203.xxx.xx.xxx:4xxx/Feeds/Connect?UserId=abcd&Password=zxcv&ServiceLevel=17&Group=*&protocol=TCP

According to my Manager, he says : "Connect to above URL as a socket from your Android device & you will start getting the Stream of Feeds."

But as per my R&D on Sockets, a socket connection just needs an IP & a port. i.e.

**Socket socket = new Socket("IPADDRESS","PORT-Number")**
& socket connection does not need a URL.

Thus, colleagues please guide me that i am gng wrong somewhere or my the backend ppl have misguided my Manager !

---

## **Updated Question:**

Please suggest some working, final Tutorial for Socket connection (Which provide data as a Stream.)

I have checked many tutorials but they guide to setup our own Server.
Please suggest some tutorial with Server implemented.

Comment: Sockets in the way that you are describing them are on another level of the OSI-model (sockets are the 'transport' layer while HTTP is the 'application' layer). You probably need an HTTP client instead.

Comment: @Thomas: I tried using HTTPURLCONNECTION in "GET" method, & i was getting success response also. (Connection method == 200), but i am not getting any Stream of feeds.

Comment: @Thomas: Can u please guide how to send data to Server once we open the Socket-Connection,
Suppose i did,
**`Socket socket = new Socket(IPADDRESS, PORTNUMBER);`**
**//Now how to send data to server.**

Comment: Then you have to do a GET request. Just a few lines of text to send. Google for http get request. Your manager is wrong. If you implement all yourself with a socket you will understand the http protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You don't connect t a URL like that via a socket.  Well I guess you could, but it would be a lot of work.  That URL is an http URL.  You connect to it via the Http protocol.  In Android, that's an HttpUrlConnection.  But you would not use a tcp socket unless you want to implement all of HTTP.

Comment: Ok, will get back to the Back-end team & let them know that this is not a SocketConnection, this is HTTP connection & we cannot connect HTTP to fetch Stream. Bacon, if we do so, the Battery of device will drain.

I will let you know what they say.

Comment: They said: its a connection tunnel, we are not closing the connection from the Server side. Try to send Parameters after you open the Socket. ! :-(

I don't know how to do that !
i.e. Socket socket = new Socket();
What after this....(How to i send data to server after this !)

Comment: ...I think you need to go off and study how HTTP works and read up on the protocol.  There's no way I can explain everything you're saying wrong in the space of a post here.  You might even need to go a step further back and understand how layered networking protocols work.  I can't even tell you where you or your manager are wrong, because I can't tell if he's making no sense or if you don't understand enough to relate what he said accurately.